# How to display a value inside a post with a specified category from a category custom field?

Tags: categories, taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

I added a custom field to category using ACF,
something like this:

[image]

so that I can specify a value for each category (like an image or text).
How can I call for or display this or these values inside every post with the specified category.
How do I write the code inside *single.php*?

Comment: Check the [ACF's documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/code-examples/).

Comment: @Sally CJ Sorry, I couldn't find anything that can help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_the_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) to get the categories assigned to a specific post and use [`the_field()` or `get_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/displaying-custom-field-values-in-your-theme/) to display/get the value of a specific ACF field. (You can also use [`get_term_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/) in place of `get_field()`)

So for example, the following will display a simple list of the categories (and I really mean plain simple), with the custom Image and Color fields next after the category name. Note that this assumes your Image field was set to return an *image attachment's **ID***.

```php
$cats = get_the_category();
if ( ! empty( $cats ) ) {
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ( $cats as $term ) {
        echo '<li>';

        echo $term->name;

        $selector = 'category_' . $term->term_id;

        // Display the category image.
        $att_id = get_field( 'image', $selector );
//      $att_id = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'image', true );
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $att_id );

        // Display the category color.
        the_field( 'color', $selector );
//      echo get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'color', true );

        echo '</li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped.